# Regex group in sed command

Tags: regex, sed

For the following lines

```
DEV1 ABCDEFGHI
DEV2 ABCDEFGHI
QA1 ABCDEFGHI
QA2 ABCDEFGHI
```

how do I substitute it to be the following:

```
<!-- DEV1 ABCDEFGHI -->
<!-- DEV2 ABCDEFGHI -->
<!-- QA1 ABCDEFGHI -->
<!-- QA2 ABCDEFGHI -->
```

This is what I have so far but it isn't working for all rows:

```
echo $line | sed -E 's/(QA.)|(DEV.)(.*)/<!-- \1\2\3 -->/'
```

Comment: Why bother with the subpatterns? Try using `&` to capture the whole pattern.

Comment: Can you elaborate please? Not sure what you mean.

Comment: Since `\1\2\3` covers the entire regex, it can be replaced by `&`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
echo "$line" | sed -E 's/(QA.|DEV.)(.*)/<!-- \1\2 -->/'
```

The **first group** could be prefixed by  `QA` or `DEV` 
, use the `|`  *or* operator.

A *few* **alternatives**:

```
$ echo "QA2 ABCDEFGHI"|sed -E 's/(.*)/<!-- \1 -->/'
<!-- QA2 ABCDEFGHI -->

$ echo "QA2 ABCDEFGHI"|awk '{print "<!-- "$0"-->"}'
<!-- QA2 ABCDEFGHI-->
```

Comment: Thanks. I just needed to remove the additional brackets between QA. and DEV. to define them as one group instead of two i.e. `(QA.)|(DEV.) => (QA.|DEV.)`

Comment: In fact, your first alternative is much simpler and straight forward!

Comment: So if the alternatives are acceptable... are there any input lines you do _not_ want enclosed in `<!-- -->`?